# how to use javascript to capture html document including values

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dynamic page with numerous input fields and other select menus or checkboxes. I am trying to save the page in all of it's glory into a variable, including entered text and selected menus.

`document.getElementById("mainBody").innerHTML` does capture the html, but not the inputs.

Have to stay in plain javascript. Is `document.getElementsByTagName('input')` and looping the best way to capture values?

Comment: You could iterate through them all and set their `value` / `checked` attributes, so that retrieving the `.innerHTML` of the document saves the required data

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using `outerHTML`

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('input')).forEach((e) => {
  console.log(e.outerHTML)

})
```

```html
<input value='1'>
<input value='2'>
<input value='3'>
<input value='4'>
```